How to change the value of char in C++
Hi I'm completely new to C++.
I have an assignment that is asking us to "Change the value to 97".
The first part of the task is to make a character and give it the value 'a'. Then print using cout and/or printf method. After, it asks us to change the value to 97, which I am not sure what it means or how to do it. I will put my code below for context.
What the task is asking for:

My code:

I tried to 'change the value to 97' by first changing my code like this:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     char e[97] = 'a';
     std::cout << e;
}

However, there was no change in the output in the terminal.
I then tried to change the code again like this:
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
     char e[] = 'a\97';
     std::cout << e;
}

As I was looking on the slideshows my professor had provided, and I saw the slides which had a section saying

The last character in a string array should always be terminated with a NULL character (0 value, or ‘\0’) to indicate the area of
interest in the string has ended.

And so I thought maybe I change the 0 to a 97 and that's what it means by changing the value.
I am not sure what the question is asking when it is asking me to change the value.

It says to make a (single) character. Not a character array (aka string).

you want to do char value = 'a'; then print it, then change it to char value = 97; ... you might get some compiler warnings though.

Nowhere in your assignment(the first part), it asks you to create an array. I would recommend using a good c++ book and refer to Storing int to chars

The key takeaway here is that programming by making random changes does not get you anywhere.

It's much simpler than that
char e = 'a';
cout << e;
e = 97; 
cout << e;

The point of the exercise is to show that in C++ characters (e.g. 'a') are just integers in disguise. And also that under the ASCII character set (which it is very likely that your computer is using) the character 'a' just happens to equal the integer 97.
And just to prove that characters really are integers you can write code like this
e = 'a' + 1; 
cout << e;

Take a guess what character that will print.
However it's worth saying that nothing in C++ says what characters correspond to what integers. The ASCII character set specifies such a correspondence but other character sets exist.

Okay, it all makes sense now, thank you. I just had a look through a table that showed the ASCII Character Set, and it's all making sense now.

Just had another question, after tinkering with my code and seeing what different things do, I moved onto the other parts of the question, the ones asking for me to make a C-string. Would you happen to know what it means by 'How long does this string need to be?'

@wtfamidoing C strings are implemented as arrays of char, e.g. char cstr[100]; Because arrays have a fixed size this limits the length of the string that they can hold. So whenever you declare an array to hold a C string you have to ask yourself how big do I need to make this array? That's what the question is getting at (I imagine). Also don't forget that C strings include a nul terminator, so the array has to be at least one bigger than the length of the string, e.g. the string "hello" requires an array of size at least 6.

There is no need to use array here.
You can simplify this to:
char c = 'a';
std::cout << c;
printf("%c", c);
c = 97; 
std::cout << c;
printf("%c", c);

Also see Storing int to chars

Okay, it's all making sense now. Changing the value from a character to instead, a value that corresponds with the ASCII character set, when the value is a char value, will correspond with the character set. Thank you, this helped heaps

@wtfamidoing You're welcome.
